# Hands-Free Methods of Firing Arrows for Flying Soldiers

Tags: weapons, winged-humans

**There are flying warriors wear wing suits.**

Kind of like this but with wings extending past the arms that they control with their hands

[image]

These warriors do not have the technology to make guns but they do have bows and cross bows.

**How could they combine bows or cross bows with their wing suits?**

**I am talking about a hands-free way of firing and reloading arrows while flying (darts will also work).**

Comment: Have a prehensile...tail.

Comment: Please, provide source for images you use, and make sure their license is compatible with this site.

Comment: You don't _fire_ arrows - you _shoot_ arrows. You _fire_ things that use "fire" for propulsion;  bullets, shells, rockets. Everything else, you _shoot_ or _launch_.

Comment: Are you up for a frame challenge?

Comment: Aiming is going to be difficult.  Firing a bow while flying at 160 km/h (a typical wingsuit speed) is equivalent to firing a bow while standing on the ground in a 160 km/h crosswind.

Comment: You can actually simulate a close approximation of what this would be like right now by using a bow while flying with an elytra in Minecraft. From experience: aiming is really hard; if you want to aim down, you will start to *plummet*, but if you have a lot of horizontal momentum and have gotten the aim down, you *can* get off a couple of shots before you have to focus on gliding again. (Of course, I presume you have some sort of propulsion and ability to get lift again, akin to fireworks in your hand while doing the elytra glide in Minecraft.)

Comment: And on that note: may I suggest that you actually embrace the idea that they *can't* fire hands-free, and instead must actually have the sheer skill and physical prowess to *quickly switch from wings to bow, let loose an arrow, and switch back to operating the wings*? I realize that might not be the kind of story you want to write, but it might be worth thinking about. I think you could do some really interesting and particularly exceptionally exciting and intense scenes, with that kind of premise.

Answer (score 86):

[image: Copilot]

Your warriors are going to need a co-pilot/gunnery officer.

(Note: Despite appearances, this answer does not advocate the weaponization of babies!)

Comment: LMAO!  And funny as your picture is, having a second (small light) person with you is the way to go.  Just one that is a bit older and more capable.

Comment: Beware: **BOW BABY**

Comment: So that's how Cupid gets around!

Comment: I didn’t realize “baby on board” was a *threat*!

Comment: @DougT. "Baby on board..... so watch out tailgaters"

Comment: Is that Cupid ?

Comment: Are you sure this wouldn't cause the flight suit to fail? How light would the person need to be, or what adjustments to the suit are required?

Comment: Don't worry, Henry. Not all of us won't weaponize babies.

Answer (score 47):

Just go for darts. Already done, and it work.

[War darts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flechette) were used duringg WW1. While not dropped by hand, they were still droped without any complex mecanism. Given enough altitude, kinetic energy was enough to be lethal.

[image: WW1Dart]

While you can't take as much darts as an aircraft can lift, it can still be enough to harass ennemy, and would be much easyer to use than bow/crossbow

Comment: This was even done in the Viet Nam war, with the darts having additional energy due to the much higher altitude and airspeed they were being dropped from.

Comment: Or alternatively drop oil then have a ground-based archer fire a flaming arrow. Weight would be an issue so you need many gliders but for area of denial it should be very effective

Comment: @LordJebusVII I'm not sure individual flyers would be able to carry enough oil to be able to coat any significant area, and certainly not with enough continuity (even with a small fleet of flyers) that a couple of flaming arrows would actually ignite it all.

Comment: @DoktorJ Even flaming arrow concept is odd. When you loose an arrow, it get massive acceleration,and achieve non negligeable speed, so the fire in the arrowhead should be massive in order to not vanish

Comment: Nah, not with the proper fuel (pitch works great and is easy to source even in medieval scenarios) and, at the expense of accuracy, a custom arrowhead could be made such that at least some part of the flame is maintained in the arrow's "slipstream" and thus not easily blown out -- as soon as the arrow hits its mark, any burning areas that may have been suppressed by airflow will happily re-ignite.

Comment: Yeah, wasn't sure if the mass would be too great, flaming arrows were certainly used in medieval warfare though. Not sure how much lift a low-tech wingsuit would generate. +1 for darts though

Comment: good video of lindeybeige about fire arrows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTd_0FRAwOQ

Answer (score 10):

## FIRE!!!

Yes, having crossbows as weapons would work*.  Four across the back, firing forward, as air to air missiles.  Four across the chest, firing down, as air to surface missiles.  Each one is connected by a wire to one of the pilot's fingers.  While that digit is curled, the wire is loose.  Straighten the finger, the wire is pulled taut and the connected crossbow fires.

## RELOAD!!!

Low tech automatic crossbows exist.  The [Mythbusters built one](https://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/videos/arrow-machine-gun-high-speed-3) (though at ballista size).  They have a gravity loading magazine, and a crank to pull the string back between shots.  You could have the crank mechanism be tied to the pilot rolling or waving their wrist.

An alternative (or maybe an addition) would be to have a sail connected to the bowstring.  After the crossbow is fired, the sail is pulled taut, and the force of the wind on the sail pulls (or at least helps to pull) the bowstring back.

## What a drag*

Here's the thing.  The crossbows you could sell.  There are some fairly light but powerful crossbows out there.  Crossbows fired by tripwires and pressure plates are moderately well known (you could use the tripwire example as a lampshade).

The reloading?  Not so much.  Gravity fed magazines stick up and out by design.  They add a lot of drag and more weight, neither of which is good for a wingsuit.  Plus if the pilot needs to dive or roll, the gravity feeder won't work, or since they are touchy as is, might get out of alignment.

On top of that, neither of the reloading methods are especially believable for a wingsuit.  Neither one is going to provide the force to cock a reasonably deadly crossbow, at least without adding a lot of weight or drag.  Which, as mentioned before, is bad.

## TL;DR

Crossbows as weapons without needing hands, yes.  Reloading, not so much.

Comment: "*FIRE!!!*" if you told a medieval archer or crossbowman to *fire*, they'd be really confused what you mean. For bows, the command is "Shoot!" or "Release!" since, you are letting go of the bow string. Crossbows similarly shoot. You *fire* a gun. Well, anything with gunpowder, since you are literally creating a fire to get the projectile to move.

Comment: The sail idea seems strange - won't the sail interfere with the string during release ("shooting"?), significantly reducing the power transferred to the corssbow's bolt?

Comment: Maybe an alternative to a sail tied to the string (lot of drag, plus possible interference with shooting), consider a wind powered crank - maybe something like a [cup anemometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemometer#Cup_anemometers) (a "cup weather vane")? It'll take longer to pull the string, but it shouldn't interfere with firing, and likely to present significantly less drag...

Comment: Try "loosing" or "Loose!" for arrows and other non-fired projectiles.

Answer (score 10):

If your world has clockwork, you could (in theory) have a clockwork mechanism that [reloads and cocks a spring-fed repeating crossbow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_crossbow), and be activated with a. This probably wouldn't be very powerful, so (as per the original) poison tips could be used to increase the effect. It would also be rather heavy.

You mentioned that the flying warriors control their flight with their hands, thus another possibility would be to have a fixed tail, allowing for a bow to be cocked using the legs. I imagine some sort of stirrup that one pushes back to cock.

Comment: Please do not ask questions in answers. This post would be better phrased as a clarifying comment. "Does your world have clockwork?" means that the validity of this answer (and whether or not it should be deleted) depends on user feedback. -1. Reporting to moderation. Will check back later.

Comment: I have zero problem with using a question rhetorically and do it myself.  I do not feel it violates the "no questions in answers" rule if it's easily reworded.  So I reworded it for the poster.  I can't do anything about the error though (activated with a...what!?) and hopefully the poster will fix that.

Comment: @Cyn fair enough

Comment: @TheGreatDuck keep in mind the code of conduct. This is a new user, and things like "-1, reporting to moderation" are not necessary, and might drive then away from the site. Better would be to teach then about the [help] section and encourage then to take the [tour] (which I see they haven't done yet).

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE! In my other comment I mention some resources you may want to check out to learn about this community. Questions in answers against policy, so Cyn slightly reworded your answer with the same meaning. As it is, it looks like a great answer to me, I hope you continue participating!

Comment: Hmm... Control wire to a trigger in one hand, and a set of peddles for the feet to cycle for reloading for more power than just clockwork (like the Greek cam-driven [Polybolus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polybolos))?  Or even go full-auto, and just peddle-to-fire?

Comment: @Aethenosity You are supposed to notify every single time you downvote. Anonymous downvoting is rude and unwarranted (and on some SE's is considered against the rules). Same with reports. It allows the user to contest it.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck yes, you should do so. I never suggested otherwise, just that it should be done politely. This is a brand new user writing their first question ever. Your comment came off pretty harsh/flippant. You could have said "I'm going to downvote for now, but if my issues are addressed I'll upvote later" while encouraging them that it's a good start. You could have also directed then towards the help and tour pages. That is the difference between discouraging and helpful imo. Also, while comments with dvs are encouraged, they are **not** required. I hope that explains my earlier comment

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I should also point out that the "no questions in answers" rule is to prevent people from ONLY asking questions, with no attempt to answer. One semi-rhetorical question in a real, good, answer is not against the spirit of that rule. It should really be called "no questions AS answers"

Answer (score 9):

[**Bowden cable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowden_cable) (like bicycle brakes)

<sub>A 1918 Lewis gun on a Foster mounting fitted to an Avro 504K Night Fighter. The gun trigger is operated by a Bowden cable</sub>

[image: https://new.minimania.com/images_temp/800600001g2nmb2211.jpg][image: https://new.minimania.com/images_temp/350260001g2nmb2211.jpg]

> A Bowden cable (/ˈboʊdən/ BOH-dən) is a type of flexible cable used to transmit mechanical force or energy by the movement of an inner cable relative to a hollow outer cable housing. The housing is generally of composite construction, consisting of an inner lining, a longitudinally incompressible layer such as a helical winding or a sheaf of steel wire, and a protective outer covering.

[image][image: https://fankhauserblog.files.wordpress.com/2001/07/undepressed_p8031350.jpg?w=273&h=228]

Comment: You get one shot. But you were only going to get one anyway, traveling at 200mph...

Comment: *Ballista Bombardiers Brigade* - You could have 20 color coded plungers dangling off your wrists that do different things.

Comment: And then you are too busy finding the right color to notice the incoming tree...

Comment: You could have a guy who just signals when to release, then the brigand behind all press theirs based on the signal. Would reduce the fumbling and possibly increase accuracy (or just means everyone for sure misses haha)

Comment: @Aethenosity I wouldn't want to be the guy in front of a bunch of other airborne wingsuited guys with crossbows trying to coordinate, aim, and fire. Put me anywhere *other* than in front of them please.

Comment: @DoktorJ I was imagining that pressing the trigger would _drop_ things like darts, or angle down to fire at the ground. Firing something forward would only make sense when attacking other air units, in which case the formation would break and change. Although going that fast would mean you would almost keep pace with the projectile you fire if it's from a crossbow. All in all, I see no danger for the person in front.

Comment: @Aethenosity - Negating air resistance, the projectile will travel with the extra speed already imparted from you own momentum; you will not "keep pace". We're not talking about light speed here ;) but yes, I imagine dropping things like flaming-oils.

Comment: @Mazura I didn't mean you would literally be flying next to it, just that it would be hard to aim it at really fast people, because I didn't think it would reach it's full speed (relative to the shooter). But I don't know much about it, that was just a feeling, so I believe you. What you say makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4):

In compound archery, shooting a bow without moving arms us already possible using a back tension release aid. Reloading on the other hand...

By the way, one doesn't fire arrows. Fire as a term relates to firearms. The correct terms are shoot or loose.

Comment: Welcome to the site,  David Klemis please take the [tour] and read up in our help centre about how we work: [answer] I like your answer but it's a little brief. Could you perhaps flesh it out by explaining what a "Back tension release aid" is. YOu might link to a picture of the mechanism to make it clear to our readers. :)

Comment: With this mechanism, are you still holding the bow at full draw ? This require quite a lot of power

Comment: Finally! someone else who gets irked when people talk about "firing" arrows...

Comment: @OscarBravo: Especially with the obvious pun about losing your arrows when you loose them. I mean, what kind of archer could ever resist that? :-D

Comment: @DevSolar a looser, that's who. :P

Answer (score 2):

While using a wing suit the arms and legs have to maintain a given position to provide lift. Thus cannot be moved to do anything else.

Not being able to use their hands means they cannot reload the weapon.

This immediately rules out the bow, and leaves on the stage only the cross bow.

They might wear a couple of them, one on the back and one on the chest, and have them loaded before they take off.

Once in flight they can fire the weapon by pulling a string with their mouth, once they are aligned with their target.

Answer (score 2):

Your question reminded me very much of the Siyee from Priestess of the White by Trudi Canavan. They are winged people with bat-like wings.

https://canavansbooks.fandom.com/wiki/Siyee

> The Siyee are a small race (about the size of a human child) who are light, fragile and have few magical Gifts. They have delicate bones which are easily broken. The thumb and forefinger are the only parts not in the structure of their wings, and their hands are useless for tasks that require strength.

One of the Siyee, Tryss, was an inventor and created a harness that allowed him to fire arrows like an archer while flying.

https://canavansbooks.fandom.com/wiki/Tryss

> In his spare time, Tryss made a harness which helps to injure animals, and be used for attack and defense. He tested it out to show others, and ended up gaining the help of Drilli who added a blowpipe to the contraption. He then showed the harness out to the entire group of Siyee, who realised the potential in the device.

You can read more about the harness in the actual book.

Hmm... on second thoughts I think it was a harness that held a blow dart pipe and allowed him to fire darts from it.

Comment: Would you mind copying the pertinant information to the answer? Links alone are generally discouraged. Good answer though

Comment: @Aethenosity done. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a youtube video of a [automatic cross-bow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QS4RKoRyTik).  The main problems would be

1) Weight - every extra pound lowers both range and top speed.

2) Aim - Because hands and feet have to stay in the "Flying Squirrel" formation, you'll have to attach it to the warrior's chest and have them point in the general direction.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the level of technology you're looking for:

1. Blow darts, with a feeding mechanism that allows the user to suck in to feed the next dart into the barrel after one is shot. Swarms of these flying blow-dart soldiers would be mentally terrifying as well, hearing a thousand "Thoot, huff, thoot, huff, thoot, huffs" as they fly overhead.
2. Crossbows attached to the lower legs that could be fired by flicking your feet forward. Reloading could be accomplished by pulling the foot back which triggers a mechanism to feed a new arrow in.
3. Chest/back mounted bolt gun attached to a computer riddled suit. AR visor helmet with iris tracking features allows the 'pilot' to seek out a target, and blink twice to fire, or simply say "FIRE!"

Answer (score 1):

They would use a horse bow (also known as a mongolian recurve bow) for the small size and lightness. They would have a mechanism to allow them to briefly lock the wings in extended positions and then retract their hands from the suit in order to fire. They would not be able to maneuver except for minor corrections through their legs while firing but that would be fine to allow strafing runs.

With training they would be able to lock the wings, fire off a few shots, then grab the wings again and continue flying.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't think of an ideal way of doing this. Best I could come up with is some sort of spear system where the pilot releases them with a button or such. But it wouldn't be effective nor would you have enough ammo. If you had people in wing suits, your best bet would just to be to use them as artillery, as aiming is tough and they can't fly indefinitely, so dropping things would be more effective than shooting. Hence heavier objects would be more useful, but then they can't fly...

But I was thinking about your question, and I'm not sure but you say they're flying warriors. If they are in fact flying and can go up and not just glide, (unlike the wingsuit you referenced), then they'd probably have a completely different device. You say the wings expand past the arms. I assume they flap their arms in a similar manner to birds to fly?

Perhaps your warriors would be using something similar to the flying machine in assasins creed? [image]
Maybe it would bend along the center to allow the warriors to move the wings.

If so then you could have a rope over the top that holds the wings in place without the user having their hands in place, so perhaps they can push the wings out with their hands so the rope becomes taut and then equip a bow and arrow, the rope holding the wings at the current extention so they're gliding across the battlefield raining death from above.